# Access variables in Python using Apache Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following Python code executed in Airflow.

```
    calculate_phase = BashOperator(
        task_id='calculate_phase',
        bash_command='python3 /home/path to /sql.py -s some_name -e dev -f /sql folder path/count_lowercase.sql'.format(
                    i),
        do_xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag,
    )
 mail_phase = PythonOperator(
            task_id='mail_phase',
            dag=dag,
            python_callable=chk_mail,
            provide_context=True,
        )
```

- `sql.py` is python script for Snowflake connection,aws details,and finally contains

`res = con.cursor().execute(statement).fetchone()` and in `count_lowercase.sql` I have `select count(*) from table` ,: value of this count is stored in variable `res`

But I am unable to get the value of `res` using AIRFLOW by Python Operator.Below is the following code

```
def chk_mail(**context):
 mail=context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='calculate_phase')
 print("THE VALUE IS ",mail)
```

In short ,my question is to access value  `res` which is present in `sql.py` and assign to variable mail using AIRFLOW OR XCOM

ANY SUGGESTIONS WILL BE OF GRT HELP.THANKS

Comment: First, do you have `calculate_phase >> mail_phase` in your DAG? Second, have you check the XCom value in webserver, what's the value?

Comment: @Tomasz Urbaszek,yeah i have mentioned dependencies.xcom value is none